# Want to substitute from a list of values into a string in python

Tags: python, list, loops, expression

I am trying to create a one-time use Python code snippet (or Linux commands) that I can run in Jupyter notebook for example, to take an expression of the form (having alphanumeric and special characters like / and - )

```
mytool start runprocess local:/abc/xyz/@def-123/a/ --osinstance nnnnnnnnnnnn --wait
```

and replace the `nnnnnnnn` with values taken from a list of 50 or so rows. I am fine with simply initialsing the list in the snippet into an array by pasting in the values. If placeholder `nnnnnnn` needs to be referenced by different placeholder that is fine too, since the format of the expression is in my control.

So if the input list contains 3 rows : vm123456, vm34567, vm8909090, snippet would generate output to console as follows of 3 rows:

```
mytool start runprocess local:/abc/xyz/@def-123/a/ --osinstance vm123456 --wait 
mytool start runprocess local:/abc/xyz/@def-123/a/ --osinstance vm34567 --wait
mytool start runprocess local:/abc/xyz/@def-123/a/ --osinstance vm8909090 --wait
```

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking how to replace parts of strings? Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting you guidance to solve your problem with the data you provided.

```
  #expression to be replaced   
  expression = 'mytool start runprocess local:/abc/xyz/@def-123/a/ --osinstance nnnnnnnnnnnn --wait'

  #list of possible values
  values = ['vm123456', 'vm34567', 'vm8909090']

  for v in values:

      new = expression.replace('nnnnnnnnnnnn',v)

      print(new)
      mytool start runprocess local:/abc/xyz/@def-123/a/ --osinstance vm123456 --wait
      mytool start runprocess local:/abc/xyz/@def-123/a/ --osinstance vm34567 --wait
      mytool start runprocess local:/abc/xyz/@def-123/a/ --osinstance vm8909090 --wait
```

Comment: That's not a hint